# Trouble while compiling a package that uses integral image normal estimation

Tags: eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
While compiling a package that uses integral image normal estimation and includes integral_image_normal.h, i got following error from eigen3.

```
 /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:187: error: ‘Upper’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:187: error: template argument 3 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:206: error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:206: error: ‘Upper’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:206: error: template argument 3 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:212: error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:212: error: ‘Lower’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:212: error: template argument 3 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:231: error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:231: error: ‘Lower’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:231: error: template argument 3 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237: error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237: error: ‘Upper’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237: error: ‘Dynamic’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237: error: template argument 3 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237: error: template argument 4 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255: error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255: error: ‘Lower’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255: error: ‘Dynamic’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255: error: template argument 3 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255: error: template argument 4 is invalid
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:278: error: no ‘const Eigen3::SelfAdjointView<Derived, UpLo> Eigen3::MatrixBase<Derived>::selfadjointView() const’ member function declared in class ‘Eigen3::MatrixBase<Derived>’
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:285: error: no ‘Eigen3::SelfAdjointView<Derived, UpLo> Eigen3::MatrixBase<Derived>::selfadjointView()’ member function declared in class ‘Eigen3::MatrixBase<Derived>’
  In file included from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/Core:306,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl/point_types.h:40,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl/features/integral_image_normal.h:43,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/pr2_apps/pr2_teleop/src/main.cpp:6:
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:29: error: variable or field ‘ei_manage_multi_threading’ declared void
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:29: error: ‘Action’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  In file included from /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/3rdparty/gtest/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h:51,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/3rdparty/gtest/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:57,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/3rdparty/gtest/gtest/include/gtest/gtest.h:65,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/pr2_apps/pr2_teleop/src/Grid.h:11,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/pr2_apps/pr2_teleop/src/main.cpp:11:
  /usr/include/c++/4.4/cxxabi.h:45: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
  /usr/include/c++/4.4/cxxabi.h:45: error: expected declaration before end of line
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bin/feat.dir/src/main.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bin/feat.dir/all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pr2_teleop written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/kadir/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110225-084802/pr2_teleop/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_teleop [FAIL] [ 1.08 seconds ]                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pr2_teleop. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                               
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Built 52 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] /home/kadir/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110225-084802
```

How can i solve that problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9200/trouble-while-compiling-a-package-that-uses-integral-image-normal-estimation/) by [Asil Kaan Bozcuoglu](https://answers.ros.org/users/188/asil-kaan-bozcuoglu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're missing some includes of headers from Eigen3.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0